# Unable to locate package lib32bz2-1.0

Tags: apt, package-management, 15.04

I am trying to install Simplicity studio on Ubuntu 15.04 (64-bit) and I get this error

```
E: Unable to locate package lib32bz2-1.0
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'lib32bz2-1.0'
```

I tried to install lib32bz2-1.0 package, again I get the same error. How to install package lib32bz2-1.0 on Ubuntu 15.04(64-bit)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try to install it manually by typing:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6
```

**Update:**

if you remove `lib32bz2-1.0`, it will be installed successfully.

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32stdc++6
```

**Otherwise:**

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 libstdc++6:i386 libfontconfig1:i386 libxext6:i386 libxrender1:i386 libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386
```

Comment: I am unable to install lib32bz2-1.0 pakage. I get this error
    E: Unable to locate package lib32bz2-1.0
    E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'lib32bz2-1.0'

Comment: The package lib32bz2 [appears to have been discontinued after Utopic](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=lib32bz2&searchon=names). My *guess* is that it has been replaced by a true multiarch (`:i386`) package - perhaps [libbz2-1.0:i386](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/i386/libbz2-1.0/filelist)

Comment: I installed libbz2-1.0:i386 instead of lib32bz2-1.0... it works now

Comment: In Ubuntu 15.10, I just had to edit the setup.sh script in the SimplicityStudio folder and replace there "lib32bz2-1.0" with the suggested "libbz2-1.0:i386". After that, the setup.sh finished successfully.

Answer (score 48):

The package (32 bit) you are looking for is `libbz2-1.0:i386`, its 64 bit version is `libbz2-1.0:amd64`.

At first enable multi-arch support (if not done already):

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Now run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

You can now install the package by:

```
sudo apt-get install libbz2-1.0:i386
```

Answer (score 42):

## Are you triying to install Android Studio on Ubuntu?

If you say: Yes!!. This answer is for you :-).

Maybe are you triying to install android studio with [this tutorial?](https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html?hl=es-419). It has deprecated dependencies on Ubuntu 16.04.

This command has issues:

> sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6

After a few searchs on Google I found a possible solution in this post: [Bad dependency on install command](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=207212).

This command specifies the 32 bits version of the extra libraries that you need to setup android studio. It works for me on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo apt-get install libz1 libncurses5 libbz2-1.0:i386 libstdc++6 libbz2-1.0
```

Hope it helps :-).

Comment: Look no further. This is the answer when on Ubuntu 16.04. Thanks @erknrio

Answer (score 7):

This works for me on my Ubuntu 15.04(64-bit)

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 libbz2-1.0:i386 lib32stdc++6
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install libz1 libncurses5 libbz2-1.0 libstdc++6
```

without 32

Comment: What does this add to the 4 other answers?