# Dependency problems when trying to install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32stdc++6

Tags: 16.04, software-installation

I am trying to install packages with this command:

```
sudo apt-get -f install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32stdc++6
```

But I am getting errors during the installation. Error looks like:

```
pkg-name : Depends: pkg-name (= X.X) but it is not going to be installed
```

Here are some screenshots:

[image: Errors - 1]

[image: Errors - 2]

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/637113/unable-to-locate-package-lib32bz2-1-0 maybe the solution ...

Comment: "http://askubuntu.com/a/771791/437449" you can try this solution.

Comment: If you were dealing w/ PPAs, then a solution could be found [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: @TONTONFLASH I don't think that is the solution because here apt isn't reporting package not found. instead showing dependency error. 

Bhvya Dhiman, please post your `apt-cache policy` output to the post [editing]() it. also `apt-cache policy gcc-5-base`

Answer (score 4):

Those packages have been replaced under the newer multiarch specification, so add :i386 to specify the 32-bit version if you are running a 64-bit system, otherwise APT will assume you want the 64-bit version.

This works for me in Ubuntu 16.04:

```
sudo apt install zlib1g:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386
```

Thanks to [comment by TONTONFLASH](https://askubuntu.com/questions/820466/unable-to-install-packages-dependency-problems/820499#comment1244333_820466) leading to the other post where [another comment by steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/637113/unable-to-locate-package-lib32bz2-1-0#comment910010_637121) gave the necessary hint.

Comment: The packages are same. but if you want to install 32bit packages in a 64bit system, you need to append those. otherwise apt will think you wanted 64bit versions of those packages

Comment: thanks @Anwar I keep trying to clarify this post and getting distracted by chat >_< is it OK now?

Comment: did'nt work @Zanna

Comment: OK @BhavyaDhiman I may have to delete my post, but please first try doing `dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo apt update` and let me know the result

Comment: does 'nt work , permission denied, and i don't know how to apply chmod +x to this  ? @Zanna

Comment: @BhavyaDhiman sorry, you need `sudo` at the start `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` and then `sudo apt update`

Comment: @BhavyaDhiman you were requested to give the output of `apt-cache policy`

Answer (score 0):

**1. Enter this command:**

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

This is an 'apt' command to fix dependencies ("-f").

**2. Then enter this command:**

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

**3. Lastly enter this command (from 'Step 1'):**

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

---

> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

This output indicates that the above **did not** work

Comment: Source - Answer to ["How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?"](http://askubuntu.com/a/142808/562148)

Comment: OP used `-f` in the original install command

Comment: @Zanna The OP did not correctly use the command, according to my interpretation of the [man-page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man8/apt-get.8.html#contenttoc3)..

Comment: Maybe you understand man pages better than me...

Comment: What you quoted is wrong about apt. `apt` doesn't remove existing packages to satisfy a request. If it would, there would be no dependency problems at all!!